# How can I downgrade apps from the Cydia Store?

Tags: applications, jailbreak, cydia

Is it possible to downgrade apps you have upgraded in the Cydia Store? (Jailbroken) If so how would you do it?

Answer (score 2):

The only way (as far as I know having experience with Cydia repos) is to find a respiratory with the older version as when you push an update to Cydia you take out the original.

I'm sure if you run a quick google search for the version of whichever Cydia app (.deb) you are looking for you'll be able to find it.